# Next.js static generation with dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a `Template` component which builds a page based on a json structure. The json contains multiple objects including keys, which then define what component is to be used.

Like this:

```
const componentList: Record<string, any> = {
    BlockCards: dynamic<Data.BlockCards>(() =>
        import("../molecule/BlockCards").then(module => module.BlockCards)
    ),
    BlockNews: dynamic<Data.BlockNews>(() =>
        import("../molecule/BlockNews").then(module => module.BlockNews)
    ),
    PageHeader: dynamic<Data.PageHeader>(() =>
        import("../atom/PageHeader").then(module => module.PageHeader)
    ),
};

interface TemplateProps {
    data: Data.Main;
}

export const Template: React.FC<TemplateProps> = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {data.content.map((item, index) => {
                const Component = componentList[item.component.type];

                if (!Component) return null;

                return (
                    <Block key={index}>
                        <Component {...item.component} {...props} />
                    </Block>
                );
            })}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

This works, but the components are lazy loaded on the client's side. I want the rendering to happen on build, just like with `getStaticProps`. Importing my components without using `dynamic` works and the components will be prerendered thanks to next's static optimization. But since this one Template components imports multiple components that might not be used by some pages, I need the components to be only imported if used - how can I do so?